# MySQL Workbench Select Breaking With utf8mb4 Field

Tags: utf-8, mysql-workbench, iso-8859-1, utf8mb4

In effort to support emoji's I converted a field on my table from latin1 to utf8mb4. The table has around 5million items and the conversion process took about an hour.

Now I'm noticing something very strange, when I select a result with an emoji, the query executes and freezes MySQL WorkBench - and no result is returned - and it breaks subsequent working queries. I have to exit WorkBench and re-enter to get things to work correctly again.

It just breaks if it show's a result with an emoji in it. I can do a full select and omit the utf8mb4 field and it works every time, it's just when I select * and the emoji data is included it breaks workbench.

I've tried: `SET NAMES utf8mb4;`before the query and no luck. The results come back fine using any other means, this is just a WorkBench issue. Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: "Breaks"?  Splinters on the floor?  Crash?  Hang?

Comment: What connection parameters are you using?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  `SELECT HEX(col) ...` to see one of the Emoji.

Comment: By "breaks" I mean crashes MySQL Workbench - I can still click around the interface, but when trying to run queries on the current db or even another, it returns no results. It's as if, Workbench can't handle the encoding of the results returned and it breaks the interface logic.

Comment: The columns i edited are showing correctly as `title` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL, `desc` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: Select HEX works in returning the column result - but oddly enough, it lets me do a select on the utf8mb4 columns anyway if I'm selecting just a few columns at once (including the utf8mb4 ). It's when I do a select all * or list the columns out individually it seems to crash Workbench

Comment: File a bug report with bugs.mysql.com -- but you may need to provide a dump of the data that led to the crash.  Meanwhile, use the mysql command line tool to access your data.